# XML: content is not allowed in trailing section

Tags: xml

I'm getting these errors

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed 
     (invalid token)
    - Content is not allowed in trailing section.
```

on this XML file...

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
    android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_red" />
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_orange" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_orange" />
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_black" />
</selector>
```

Probably quite simple for you people who know XML. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a close selector tag or this is the complete XML file?

Comment: its the whole xml file. i followed this guide..

http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/

Comment: You can check these characters using an editor like notepad++. Check in ANSI mode (Encoding -> encoding in ANSI) you can see observe them right next to closing tags.

Comment: @Capsud Please can you provide us the **exact** xml content as it was on the guide from where you copied (The link is dead). I have similar error and not able to figure out the cause :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you pasted it from the site you link to, there are two little hyphens you don't want.  One after the close of `</selector>` and one just before the first `<item>`.  Get rid of those, and all will be well.

Comment: Can you edit the XML file with character errors? It will be useful (I have the same problem).

Comment: The error cannot be spotted from the question content, and links are dead.

Answer (score 6):

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Test App</string>
</resources>
testData("test");
```

If in any xml file unfortunately this type of line is remaining then this error is occur.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have any extraneous characters after the closing tag (I'm assuming what you posted is just an excerpt from the file, since it obviously won't work without at least a closing  tag)?

Comment: nope, the file is exactly what i posted except that </selector> is there. I edited my original post to add that in but for some reason its still not showing.
Anyway i do have the closing tag there.

ugh so weird..?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well after multiple modifications on the file, I just cut out the content and pasted to Notepad++ (to remove any formatting). Saved my empty .xml file and closed the project. Reopened the project and put back the data from Notepad++. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Some end tag character like '>' should be there in your xml. Remove this and error will be gone.