# I can not run my application Android Studio

Tags: android

Can you help me please?

When I try to run, the compiler show me this. Some idea? Thanks[image]

This is the AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cyrax.rocas">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Infoclase"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please share your android manifest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946528/xml-content-is-not-allowed-in-trailing-section

Comment: Something is in this manifest that isn't visible. I checked it against the xml validator here and found no errors. http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0

Comment: better you can write your manifest again. Clean and rebuild your project and run again.

Comment: it is an error that u added some unknown character at the end of the manifest (rebuild manifest) and clean build the app again.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and rebuild it.